# Selenium version 3.141 can't execute driver path

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm using an older version of Selenium (version 3.141.0) in local environment with Python 3.11, because I won't have the permission to update the webservers' version later on.

Now I have a problem that I can't get a python script working, because of some error which the drivers' path is throwing.

The chromedriver.exe is in the same directory as the python script.

**This is my Python script (test2.py):**

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\yyy\\Desktop\\paytho\\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get('https://www.yyyy.com')

driver.maximize_window()

print(driver.title)

driver.close()
```

**And this error is shown in the terminal of VS Code:**

```
PS C:\Users\yyy> & C:/Users/yyy/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.11.exe c:/Users/yyy/Desktop/paytho/test2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\yyy\Desktop\paytho\test2.py", line 3, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\yyy\\Desktop\\paytho\\chromedriver.exe")
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\yyy\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 76, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "C:\Users\yyy\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\yyy\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\yyy\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 319, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\yyy\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 374, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\yyy\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 397, in _request
    resp = self._conn.request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\yyy\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\urllib3\_request_methods.py", line 118, in request
    return self.request_encode_body(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\yyy\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\urllib3\_request_methods.py", line 217, in request_encode_body
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\yyy\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 432, in urlopen
    conn = self.connection_from_host(u.host, port=u.port, scheme=u.scheme)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\yyy\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 303, in connection_from_host
    return self.connection_from_context(request_context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\yyy\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 328, in connection_from_context
    return self.connection_from_pool_key(pool_key, request_context=request_context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\yyy\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 351, in connection_from_pool_key
    pool = self._new_pool(scheme, host, port, request_context=request_context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\yyy\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 265, in _new_pool
    return pool_cls(host, port, **request_context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\yyy\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 196, in __init__
    timeout = Timeout.from_float(timeout)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\yyy\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\urllib3\util\timeout.py", line 190, in from_float
    return Timeout(read=timeout, connect=timeout)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\yyy\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\urllib3\util\timeout.py", line 119, in __init__
    self._connect = self._validate_timeout(connect, "connect")
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\yyy\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\urllib3\util\timeout.py", line 156, in _validate_timeout
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Timeout value connect was <object object at 0x0000020042E84560>, but it must be an int, float or None.
```

Comment: Looks like a driver version mismatch to me. Selenium 3.141 is 5 years old. Are you also using a ChromeDriver that is about that old? If you use a recent ChromeDriver with this old version, this is sure to cause issues. Now, an old ChromeDriver will have issues with newer Chrome browsers, so you'd also need to use an old Chrome. 
Not sure to understand why the webserver version has anything to do with Selenium and Chrome versions...

Comment: The problem is that the webserver has Selenium version 3.141 installed and I'm not able to upgrade it. But thanks it will be probably a driver mismatch.